# Special name for two rows of knights with raised swords?

Tags: military, royalty

1. Is there a special name to describe the formation of knights that form a row of arches with their swords (for a special person to walk through)?
2. Was such a formation historically accurate, or only something depicted in movies and art?
3. If real, which countries/cultures, time periods, and circumstances would it have been used in?

Comment: What, you mean like a [saber arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_arch)?

Comment: I've always called it a Guard of Honour - for instance, for bride and groom leaving the church at a military wedding - but don't know if this is the formal name for it.

Comment: A side note: this formation was sometimes used for punishment.

Comment: When one of the volunteer cleaners at our church got married, the other cleaners formed an Honour Guard/Arch  - with mops!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Congusbongus was correct.  I'm submitting the answer because no answer has been submitted.  I don't think it goes back to the middle ages.  In the United States it's called the "**saber arch**" and we get it from the British Navy.

It's a tradition at weddings of military service members, typically when exiting the building in which the wedding ceremony took place.  Typically performed by members of the groom/brides? service branch/unit.

Germany and Austria have a similar ceremony for fraternities.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_arch